# What is the T-SQL to list all elastic pools in an Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-elasticpool

I have more than one Azure SQL Server which each may contain at least one SQL Elastic Pool. I am trying to build a SQL script that can execute a CREATE DATABASE statement on any of those servers and select one of the available pools on that server. To that end, I would like to know the T-SQL statement which would list all the available elastic pools on this server. I have found the SQL below which will list all the databases on the server and which pool they are in:

```
SELECT d.database_id, d.name, elastic_pool_name
FROM sys.databases d
JOIN sys.database_service_objectives dso ON d.database_id = dso.database_id
```

However, this only returns `master` on a new server so I can't tell what the pool name(s) are to create a new database in a pool on the server. I also found this REST API endpoint to [list all elastic pools on a server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-02-01-preview/elastic-pools/list-by-server), but I need to execute this in SQL and not via HTTP.

Comment: have you tried the `sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats` view?

Comment: For a new server with no databases, sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats appeared to return no records :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of elastic pools on the server from sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats

```
select distinct @@servername as servername, elastic_pool_name from sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats
```

[image]

Comment: It appears on a new server that the results list is empty, but this is the best I have found so far, thanks!